# Just how reserved are the words private and public in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, private, public

Each time I build a JS library I have this sort of concept:

```
(function(window,undefined){
  var LibName = function(){
    var privateAPI = {
      method: function(){}
    };
    var publicAPI = {
      publicMethod: function(){}
    };
    return publicAPI;
  }
  window.LibName = LibName;
})();
```

But i've always longed for just doing:

```
(function(window,undefined){
  var LibName = function(){
    var private = {
      method: function(){}
    };
    var public = {
      publicMethod: function(){}
    };
    return public;
  }
  window.LibName = LibName;
})();
```

But I've never done that because those are reserved words. Just how reserved are they? Will a browser fail? In my testing, everything seems to work, but am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing the notion that overloading language reserved words is a bad idea. ;>  Not because it will confuse the browser, but because it will confuse the humans who try to read or debug your code.

Comment: And that in the future, it may cause problems, such as when JS (EcmaScript) decides to support private variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

and

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf for the official specification.

They're listed in 7.6.1.2 as "reserved for future use".

Answer (score 15):

Always assume that using reserved words improperly will cause the application to fail.

Words like `public` and `private` are [future reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words), so even if they work now the might not in the future.

Comment: Actually, in ES6 they will work just fine as property names.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend to use private and public. But you'll get an error only by using strict mode with "use strict": https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode

If you want to be sure, it will work in the future, you would have to use parentheses:

```
this["private"] = {
  method: function() {}
}
```

I prefer to shorten the var to "pub" and "priv". So I use a pattern like this:

```
namespace.decorator = function (pub, priv) {
  pub = pub || {};
  priv = priv || {};
  //namespace.decoratorToExtend(pub, priv);
  pub.method = function() {alert(pub.prop)};
  return pub;
}
var instance = namespace.decorator({prop:'hello world'});
instance.method();
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I've experienced with reserved words in javascript the code will error out with something like a syntax error.

Comment: -1. It's not necessarily true. You can use keywords like public and private if not in the strict mode, although this is discouraged.